# How do I get a label to display random text when a button is pressed? [Swift]

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm currently developing my first app, and i'm completely stuck with generating random text in a label when a button is pressed. Here's a bit more information:

the app is a very simply studying tool which will help me remember quotes from famous historians (i know i could use a pen and paper but this way is more fun and my friends can use it too).

Here's what i have:

```
@IBAction func quoteButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1
    var QuoteString:String = String(format: "quote%i", randomNumber)

    self.quoteLabel.text = QuoteString

    var quote0 = "Quote 000"
    var quote1 = "Quote 001"
    var quote2 = "Quote 002"
    var quote3 = "Quote 003"
    var quote4 = "Quote 004"
    var quote5 = "Quote 005"
    var quote6 = "Quote 006"
}
```

(Code image found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GURL.png))

So as you can see, the random generator adds a number to the prefix 'quote' and then the label (quoteLabel) displays the outcome 'Quotestring' (The prefix and the random number put together)

However, what happens is the label just displays the text 'quote1' or 'quote3' and not the variable that i have attached to those "Quote 000"

How do i get the Label to display the variables ("Quote 000"), and not just what i have called them (quote5) - have i done anything majorly wrong, or am i missing something small?

A little more info:

- Quote 000 - 006 are just what i have called them to test, and will be replaced with quotes.
- The app runs fine in the iOS simulator, it just repeatedly displays 'quote0' or 'quote5' etc.

Thanks a lot, any help would be great!

Comment: For the love of all. please paste and format code into questions.

Comment: Down vote for posting the code as image.

Comment: Sorry about that, i will do next time!

Answer (score 4):

Don't create a bunch of separate quote variables. Create an array of quotes:

```
let quotes = [
  "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country",
  "Vini, vidi, vichi",
  "I regret that I have but one life to give for my country",
  "Illegitimi non carborundum"
  ]

let index = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quotes.count))
let aQuote = quotes[index]
```

By the way, don't post images of code. Use Code tags to put the code into your post, like I did above.

Comment: `let index = arc4random_uniform(quoteArray.count)` - will not work in Swift 1.2 and Swift 2 since `arc4random_uniform` cannot take an Int.

Comment: Ok, it'll need a type-cast. I am posting an outline of how to do it, not tested code.

Answer (score 2):

> How do i get the Label to display the variables ("Quote 000"), and not just what i have called them (quote5) - have i done anything majorly wrong, or am i missing something small?

The problem is that this line of code `var QuoteString: String = String(format: "Quote 00%d", randomNumber)` is literally assigning a `String` value to `QuoteString`. It is not referencing your variables  `quote0` .. `quote6` and their associated quotes. You are literally telling it that `QuoteString` = the bit in "" + the random number.

These 2 lines I think do what you you are trying to achieve.

```
    let quoteArray = ["Quote 000", "Quote 001", "Quote 002", "Quote 003", "Quote 004", "Quote 005", "Quote 006"]
    self.quoteLabel.text = quoteArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray.count)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just using a string anyways you don't need to have all the string vars that's extra code. Just use:

```
var QuoteString:String = String(format:Quote 00%d,randomNumber)
```

or

```
var QuoteString:String = String(format:Quote 00\(randomNumber))
```

you shouldn't use a string like that to choose a variable name. The other option is to use a Switch Case but the above code is by far the best option.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful indeed!

Comment: But it's not the answer, he doesn't just want to put "Quote 00"+randomNumber, he wants to put in a random quote, like "To be or not to be?" or "Ask not what your country can do for you," the strings in the variables are just filler, @Ven

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're just creating a string object and putting it in the label. Also, you want to be referencing a variable, but you're doing it before you declare the variables. Your range is also not quite right, your random number will yield something between 1-5, but you want 0-6. You could put a 7 in and take away the +1, but I would do it differently.

I would personally put them all in an array and do it like this:

```
@IBAction func quoteButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let quotes: NSArray = ["Quote 000", "Quote 001", "Quote 002", "Quote 003", "Quote 004", "Quote 005", "Quote 006"]

    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(quotes.count)

    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
    let QuoteString = quotes.objectAtIndex(randomNumber)

    self.quoteLabel.text = QuoteString as? String

}
```